# Making a form submit without field changes after a SubmissionError

Tags: redux-form

I have a redux-form component that behaves as two components: a login and a signup form. I control this behavior using state. When the "Signup" button is clicked, the component state changes, and so does the `handleSubmit` function: to a signup or login function.

Now lets say I get a `SubmissionError`, and the form `redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_FAILED` action is dispatched. My form nicely displays the error, but if I change the form state and then submit the form again (without changing the fields), nothing happens.

As an example of this suppose I try to login, get a login error, and then realize that I really wanted to create a new account, not to login. I'm guessing that it has to do with `SET_SUBMIT_FAILED` which disables submit until at least one field has changed.

How can I change this behavior? Is there a way to make form accept another submit after a submit error?

Is there another way of managing a signup/login form in a single component through redux-form?